# Varnish serves wrong files

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

i'm using a varnish 3 behind a nging to proxy multiple sites into one domain.
The basic setup works fine but I now have a problem with varnish serving the wrong files if the filename already exists in it's cache.
Basically all I do in my default.vcl is this:

```
   if(req.url ~ "^/foo1") {
        set req.backend = foo1;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/foo1/", "/");
    }
    else if(req.url ~ "^/foo2") {
        set req.backend = foo2;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/foo2/", "/");
    }
```

If I now call /foo1/index.html, /foo2/index.html will serve the same file. After a restart of varnish and a call of /foo2/index.html, /foo1/index.html will serve foo2's index.html.

As far as I found out this is an issue with the creation of the hash which does not respect the used backend but only the url (after shortening) and the domain:

```
    11 VCL_call     c hash
    11 Hash         c /index.html
    11 Hash         c mydomain
```

I solved this issue for now by altering my vcl_hash to also use the backend but I'm sure there must be a better, more convenient way:

```
    sub vcl_hash {
      hash_data(req.url);
      hash_data(req.backend);
    }
```

Any hint would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways of doing this. First one, is to do what you suggested by adding extra values (e.g. `req.backend`) in `vcl_hash`.

```
sub vcl_hash {
   hash_data(req.url);
   hash_data(req.backend);
}
```

Second way, is to not update `req` in `vcl_recv`, but only `bereq` in `vcl_miss/pass`.

```
sub vcl_urlrewrite {
    if(req.url ~ "^/foo1") {
        set bereq.url = regsub(req.url, "^/foo1/", "/");
    }
    else if(req.url ~ "^/foo2") {
        set bereq.url = regsub(req.url, "^/foo2/", "/");
    }
}
sub vcl_miss {
    call vcl_urlrewrite;
}
sub vcl_pass {
    call vcl_urlrewrite;
}
sub vcl_pipe {
    call vcl_urlrewrite;
}
```

This second approach requires more VCL but it comes with advantages as well. For example, when analyzing logs with `varnishlog`, you can see the vanilla request (`c` column), and also the updated backend request (`b` column).

```
$ varnishlog /any-options-here/
(..)
   xx RxURL        c /foo1/index.html
(..)
   xx TxURL        c /index.html
(..)
$
```

Comment: Thank you! The second approach looks and works fine, just tested!